# Surefire configuration in POM and from command line

Tags: java, maven, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

From [*Maven Surefire Plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) docs:

> If you have multiple executions configured in surefire plugin within your POM, you may want to execute the only default test phase:
> `mvn surefire:test -Dtest=TestCircle`

I didn't understand what is the priority/overriding between the POM config and the command-line.

I have these plugin configurations in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now I'm trying to run my tests with

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.includesFile=.\Path\To\includesFile -Denv=IsProfileValueTag
```

And I'm expecting only the classes in the `includesFile` to run, but all the tests with the `IsProfileValueTag` running.

Comment: Remove the dependency from maven-surefire-plugin configuration let Maven / Surefire handle the correct provider. Add the appropriate dependency in your pom file. Remove the includes configuration because it's default. What is the reason to override the configuration on command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise I removed the dependency from the question because it was irrelevant.
The `includes` configuration is not the default, the default only includes `Test`, see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html. The reason is that I have a script that decides at runtime which tests to run and write them to the `includesFile`

Comment: It does not make sense to change the defaults (if those are given the defaults or not). Convention over configuration. I don't understand why you are having a script which decides the tests to run? Are those tests unit tests? If yes those test should run all ...otherwise you might break code without knowing it... More complicated then needed... If your tests are too slow parallelize them...using JUnit Jupiter etc. you can simply do... if those tests are really unit tests if not you are running them in the wrong phase...

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that there are a lot of companies that do wrong things, and can not change the existing situation and start writing all the tests by the book.

Comment: Which in consequence produces a lot of problems they have instead of doing it the right way... but that does not help (I know a lot about the issue companies/people doing it wrong)...apart from that I don't say write tests following a book but follow some naming conventions and let do some tools their work which they are doing very good for a very long time only some people think they know it better. Furthermore you should use the referenced documentation and do not use trying to change the includes statement.Or do your test don't have a naming convention?

Comment: The question is: What is that magical script really doing? And why do you need it? What is the advantage of the script?